# WPF DataGrid ObservableCollection linked to Checkbox list adding extra row

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two windows in my WPF application.

1. a main window which has a collection of checkboxes bound to "Name" properties in an ObservableCollection
2. a Settings Window with a Datagrid that is bound to all the objects in that ObservableCollection, Name, Date, Memo  etc.

Whenever I open the Settings Window via the Main Window, because the DataGrid has CanUserAddRows=true, the list of checkboxes in the main windows gets an extra row added which just shows a blank checkbox with no content. Then when I close the settings window, this extra blank line persists. Is there any way (which is MVVM complaint) to keep CanUserAddRows to true, but remove that extra added line when the Settings Window is closed?

Comment: You could use two separate `ObservableCollection`s, that should help. The problem right now is that when you add a row in the settings it's adding an object to the shared `ObservableCollection`. Instead of using the same one, you can pass the data to the settings window and initialize a new `ObservableCollection` there. Adding rows in the settings window shouldn't have any effect on the main windows collection then.

Comment: If I go this route, what would be the best way to reflect the changes into the original ObservableCollection?

Comment: In that case, I'd set the `DataGrid`'s `CanUserAddRows` property to `False` and only allow adding new items via a `Button`. That button would do something like `MyObservaleCollection.Add(new Item())`. That would create an empty item but only when the user would want to do it.

Comment: I've created an example repo you can check out at https://github.com/michaldivis/ObservableCollectionEditingTest

Comment: Thanks Michal - but the link seems to be broken?

Comment: I've set it up as a private repo. I'll change it to public so you can view it.